# In what order should I install SQL Server Developer Edition and Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

Yes, there are many "Questions that may already have [my] answer" on StackOverflow, however, they refer to older versions of Visual Studio, or SQL Express, or SQL Enterprise Manager.

I'd like to know the correct install sequence for SQL Server Developer Edition (2012) and Visual Studio 2013.  Additionally, since Visual Studio 2013 has a Develop for SQL Server option, which I believe installs some SQL functionality into Visual Studio, do I choose that option or not?  Choosing that option appears to install SQL Express, which I do not want.

Comment: do you mean sql server developer edition or oracle's sql developer? if the former I went with a full install of vs 2012 then a full install of sql server developer and all seems ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. SQL Server Developer Edition (2012)
2. Visual Studio 2013
3. [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx)

Comment: When I install VS 2013, do I select the "SQL Development" option?  Or will it detect that I have SQL Developer already installed?

Comment: Also, it appears the SSDT are only available through VS 2013?

Comment: I'll assume you mean SSDT WITH VS 2013 and mark answered :)  The VS 2013 installer seems to notice that SQL Developer is already installed and does not install SQL Express (deduced because no SQL Express service is installed) when SQL features are selected.  Thanks.